# The article "a" can be replaced with "any"?

Tags: meaning, grammar, articles

The following sentence "The stored program used by "a computer " permits complex solution procedures to be reprogrammed."
My instructor said in this sentence "a computer" defines any computers use stored program. Is it correct? I saw some post explains that  "*A madrigal is popular." is ungrammatical because being popular is not a requirement of being a madrigal. But they brought active voice in the explanation. This time I encountered passive voice is used in the sentence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The indefinite article **a** can refer to the noun generically, to no particular instance of the noun.

> A sandwich is usually made with two pieces of bread and something
>   in between them.

Comment: Thanks for the clear explanation. All the explanation I saw uses stative verb "is" but this time I saw action verb "the stored program used by a computer". It makes me confused. The instructor explained that "A computer uses the stored program" means any computers use the stored program. All computers are stored program computer without exception. Thanks for answering!